# Reading Git commands using Batch(.BAT) file

Tags: git, batch-file, dos

I have written DOS commands and GIT commands in notepad and convering to .BAT file.After executing the Batch file only DOS command will be executed GIT commands not executing.How do i run GIT commands using Batch(.BAT) file

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that git is in your [PATH system environment variable](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/books/5445775168.htm) and if it is then you should be able to call git just like you normally would in the terminal. Please note that you will need to restart the terminal (cmd) for path changes to take effect.

Comment: @Robert,i tried but it is not working.itwas logged and connected to GIT by running a batch file but commands were not executed..Please let me know your thoughts

Comment: @Aravinth Okay, can you do a few things for me, Type 'echo %PATH%' on the terminal and give me the output in a pastie. Then maybe show me a snippet of your batch file (or just dump your whole batch file in a pastie) and edit your question to post it so that I can see that information. With that data I should be able to spot what is going wrong or know what the next step is.

Comment: @Robert,`C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\;C:\WINNT\system32;C:\WINNT;C:\WINN
T\System32\Wbem;C:\WINNT\system32\nls;C:\WINNT\system32\nls\ENGLISH;c:\Program F
iles\Novell\ZENworks\;C:\Program Files\Novell\SecureLogin\;c:\Program Files\Pers
onal Communications\;c:\Program Files\IBM\Trace Facility\;C:\WINNT\system32\Wind
owsPowerShell\v1.0;

Comment: @Aravinth: Um, where am I supposed to find it exactly?

Comment: @Robert,c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\
Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Fi
les\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\
Tools\binn\;C:\git\tools\nant;Z:.;Y:.;X:.

Comment: @Robert,And My Batch files contains `cd C:
cd Program Files
cd Git
cd bin
sh.exe --login -i
cd c:
cd git
cd framework` In the above code it works fine till --login-i (i.e connecting to GIT) after consecutive commands it is not executing

Comment: @Robert, i forgot one command...after cd framework it shows `git pull`

Comment: @Aravinth: Ah there we go, the second that you use ssh you are logging into another machine and therefore the shell script running on your current machine will not start running until you come back to this machine. What you really want to do is run a script on the remote machine. This page explains how to: http://bashcurescancer.com/run_remote_commands_with_ssh.html

Comment: @Aravinth damn, I read too fast and read sh.exe as ssh.exe. Sorry. Also, compress all of those cd's into one line like cd "C:\Program Files\Git\bin" so that you only have one cd command per path. Also I do not see you calling git anywhere in that script but that could be due to stack overflow comments. Could you pleas put your script in a pastie: http://pastie.org/

Answer (score 1):

The git command in Msysgit is implemented by using a batch file to wrap all the calls and run the correct executable with the correct environment variables. You can not execute a batch file from another batch file normally like you would an executable, you have to use a special command to run them. If my memory is correct that command is `call` and would be used as `call git push` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Hai All,
         Finally I got the solution for my question.By using below code snippet, we can run the Git using BAT file

`"c:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.cmd" pull > c:\platform.txt`

the above code using from BAT file instead of using `git pull` or `git push` and any git command using GIT Bash

Thanks to all for posting your valuable comments and partial answer